# How can I make a beer glass to be detected by a touchscreen?

Tags: capacitance, touchscreen

I know this sounds weird, but hear me out. I was planning to build a FSR system on Arduino that detects when a beer glass is lifted off and slammed back on the coaster, showing the elapsed chug time afterwards. However, our back-to-work cottage party is coming closer and the materials will not make it in time, so I'm looking at other alternatives..

I found a Rubik's cube timer (cstimer.net) that could do the trick using an old iPad I have laying around. My idea is to use the iPad as a makeshift slam timer by opening cstimer.net on Safari and modifying the bottom a beer glass so that it is detected by the touchscreen. Any idea how I can make the bottom of a beer glass / red solo / whatever to be picked up by a capacitive screen?

I tried aluminum foil, but it was very hit or miss. Would ESD sponges work?

Comment: Wrap the foil all the way to where the glass is held from?

Comment: Did that already, but it didn't really work. The foil method doesn't maintain contact very well even if you squeeze the glass hard.

Comment: I would use a pressure sensor or a magnetic switch hooked to an Arduino. If you still need the iPad, connect to the Arduino and ask it the status.

Comment: Aluminum foil won't be correct.  Got any ESD bags that some circuit boards may have been in at some time?

Comment: are you not worried about slamming the glass onto the ipad and cracking the screen?

Comment: I do have some ESD bags, but I'm getting the same effect as aluminum foil.

@BeB00 not really, the glass will not be slammed hard. The iPad is an old piece of [rubbish] anyway that hasn't been used in years [Edited by a moderator to remove profanity.]

Comment: @TheJasonist - Hi, As you are new here, please read the [tour] and [help] to see the main site rules. There is also a longer [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931). Especially important is the Stack Exchange [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct). Although relatively mild, the profanity in your recent comment was removed. Please ensure that you comply with the site rules, and especially that policy, here in future. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try searching for "capacitive stylus." And/or "DIY capacitive stylus." Your body is a sack of electrolyte inside a skin that is a moderate conductor. A hotdog might trigger the capacitive touch better than a piece of metal. Maybe a hot dog wrapped in a plastic bag. If you are in the UK, I am not sure if you use the term "hot dog." It is the same as a "beef frank" or "wiener" or "frankfurter."

Comment: The software in the phone may suppress touch events, that cover a large area. The CapSense inputs of an ESP32 can detect such things very good.

Comment: that sounds like a recipe for disaster ... having a bunch of drunks slam drinking glasses onto an iPad